# why some php files do not end with the closing bracket "?>"?

Tags: php, syntax

I have been working with Wordpress and other CMS and I have noticed that some of the php files do not have a closing `?>`.

When I write my own files, I have to include the `?>`, otherwise the software crashes. I'm wondering how they make it work, or if there are specific sections of a theme that accept this type of php files. Maybe the closing bracket `?>` is embedded in a different file that I haven't seen.

Does anyone has an explanation for this?

If I decide to put the `?>` on these files, will the system crash? or I can safely write them with the closing bracket?

Comment: it is now best practice to leave the closing `?>` tag off from php documents to avoid having extra white space after this tag that will intern cause `headers already sent errors`

Comment: Does your software crash even when you omit closing tag in a pure php file?

Comment: I thought my files crashed if I did not included the closing tag, but I have been doing it since then and they seem fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the official PHP documentation:

> If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing
>   tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new
>   lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted
>   effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no
>   intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the
>   script.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: And that is the perfect and only answer, you'd do best to remember it and breathe a habit out of it, Will save you countless hours.

Comment: Thank you to all who answered my question. Sorry about that this question was asked before. I searched but everyone has a different way to ask the same question, so my keywords didn't show any good answers.